# How to disable “Microsoft PowerPoint failed to start correctly last time” notification

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I was wondering if anyone ever managed to be able to solve this issue as I have searched EVERYWHERE and cannot find any solution to this issue.

So quite simply I have a PowerPoint slideshow that runs as a task but PowerPoint will constantly come up and say "PowerPoint failed to start correctly last time, would you like to open in safe mode instead ?"

This is frustrating and seems to be affecting only one of three presentation computers. I have tried disabling AutoRecovery but unfortunately this did not make a difference.

Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated !

EDIT: To add more, This only occurs on every 2nd or 3rd launch attempt that is automatically invoked from the Windows Task Scheduler. When 'reset' it will (clicking "no" when it prompts to open in safe mode) open just fine when the machine is restarted as the task is set to launch on user login which has been configured to automatically login to user account on machine startup.

Obviously though this machine seems to be the bastard child, because two other machines don't have this issue and use Office 2010.

I have repaired office but again no joy, I was thinking that it would be an awesome idea to disable safe mode popup programmatically if possible to avoid this popup from stopping the slideshow event from automatically starting.

Comment: That sounds a little like throwing away the fire extinguisher  because it clashes with your décor  and you never use it.

Comment: @Scott  Hardly.... I don't require safe mode in PowerPoint when the machine doesn't get used by anyone and no other .ppt presentations run except the one .ppt file. It appeared like a valid solution if it was possible.

Comment: And apart from that, "safe mode" has nothing to do with safety from viruses/malware. Instead, it has PPT perform some tasks in software that it would otherwise hand off to e.g. the video driver. Slower, but safer if you have a driver that purports to be able to handle a given function but fails when asked to do it. You'll see people claim that safe mode also disables add-ins. Possibly true with other Office apps, but not so with PowerPoint.

Comment: Check the Event Viewer on that computer for useful information.